# Visual C++ project can't find 'xyz.h' file for external dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

I have a Visual Studio C+++ project, and in the project I have some header files I want to get via the include directories setting on the `project properties`.
As far as I know that's all set up correctly. I've added the folder path which contains the files and the 3 files appear in the `external dependencies` folder under my project in Visual Studio.

The **problem** is that:
when I write the include "xyz.h" for one of the three files, I get `"can not find file blah blah"` error. This only occurs for one of the three. The other two work fine and I can include them just fine. They are all just basic headers.

Does anyone have any idea why one of my files would fail to work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you setting up the project properties such ad `additional include directories`, make sure to select "All configurations" in the project properties window. look at the image.

[image]

Comment: I did that. I will post some screenshots in a bit when I can get them

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was that the file was being used by some background process, so the dll that I was trying to load couldn't open the file.